# How to hide the address bar of my site in small service

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, address-bar

[image]

I am trying to hide the addressbar of my website in all small device browsers. How can I make it possible. Please refer to the image. Following is my code:

```
<meta name="ap[![enter image description here][1]][1]ple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
if((Browser.Platform.ios) || (Browser.Platform.webos) && (Browser.safari)) {
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
setTimeout(function(){
window.scrollTo(0, 1);
}, 0);
});
}
```

Comment: please explane in details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="button" value="click to toggle fullscreen" onclick="toggleFullScreen()">

function toggleFullScreen() {
if ((document.fullScreenElement && document.fullScreenElement !== null) ||    
(!document.mozFullScreen && !document.webkitIsFullScreen)) {
if (document.documentElement.requestFullScreen) {  
document.documentElement.requestFullScreen();  
} else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {  
document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();  
} else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen) {      document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);  
}  
} else {  
if (document.cancelFullScreen) {  
document.cancelFullScreen();  
} else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {  
document.mozCancelFullScreen();  
} else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {  
document.webkitCancelFullScreen();  
}  
}  
}
```

Comment: here i got one solution, trying  this to get from media querries

Answer (score -2):

you can try media query in css.

```
ist of all


@media(max-width:768px){
   div.class_name{
  display:none;
 }
```

}

try this code.